# paginating joined table with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have several actions that all paginate properly, but I can't figure out what's going on with this "joined" query. It's displaying all of the posts in my table, not just the 3 at a time like I specified.

```
 public function index() { 
    $this->paginate = array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'Users',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'limit' => 3,
            'fields' => array('User.username'),
            'conditions' => array('Users.id = Post.user_id')
            )
        ));
    $posts = $this->paginate('Post');
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

**edit below here**

```
table Users
id | username | password

table Posts
id | body | user_id | created
```

This function works but it doesn't paginate.

```
public function index() { 
  $options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'Users',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'fields' => array('User.username'),
        'conditions' => array('Users.id = Post.user_id')
        )
    );
    $post = $this->Post->find('all', $options);
    $this->set('posts', $post);
}
```

Comment: One thing to add, to mimic normal cake behavior, it's helpful to add 'alias' to your joins array. Then your data result will be properly indexed (e.g. $data['alias']).

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
Your Model class should have relationship like :

Post Model :
public $belongsTo = array('User');

Post Controller :

$this->Post->recursive = 1;
$this->set('posts', $this->paginate());

Index View :
<table >
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('body'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('User.username'); ?></th>
        <tr>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo h($post['Post']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($post['Post']['body']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($post['User']['username']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:-

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Paginate not prefer join

In addition to defining general pagination values, you can define more than one set of pagination defaults in the controller, you just name the keys of the array after the model you wish to configure:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $paginate = array(
        'Post' => array (...),
        'Author' => array (...)
    );
}
```

The values of the Post and Author keys could contain all the properties that a model/key less $paginate array could.

Comment: Gives me the following error "Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'User'". Does this mean there's something up with my model?

Comment: Provide your user table name And model class name

Comment: i seen it your table name Please provide model class name or you can use Users or User in model

Comment: The classes are User and Post

Comment: I have improve my answer please take a look and try. Let me know if not working

Comment: Nope thanks for trying though. this is the error: "Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'User'".

Comment: Sorry i have mistake in code but this time is correct please try again

Comment: Nope, same error. I'll update my post above with the query that works but doesn't paginate. I'm not sure if it'll help you but I figure it can't hurt.

Comment: I have again improve my answer please take a look.

Comment: do I still ultimately use $post= $this->paginate('Post');
    $this->set(compact('post')); after defining $paginate in the index function?

Comment: That's what I meant. I first define the items I want to select using $pagiante = array(....). From here I meant do I use $post = $this->Post->find('all', $paginate); $this->set('posts', $post);

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() { 
$this->paginate = array(
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'Users',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'fields' => array('User.username'),
        'conditions' => array('Users.id = Post.user_id')
        )
    ),
   'limit' => 3);
$posts = $this->paginate('Post');
$this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the 3 steps that did the magic.

1) In First Model, simply add the $hasMany relation of First with Second

```
public $hasMany = array(
                ‘Second’ => array(
                     ‘className’ => ‘Second’,
                     ‘foreignKey’ => ‘first_id’,
                     ‘dependent’ => false,
                     ‘conditions’ => ”,
                     ‘fields’ => ”,
                     ‘order’ => ”,
                     ‘limit’ => ”,
                     ‘offset’ => ”,
                     ‘exclusive’ => ”,
                     ‘finderQuery’ => ”,
                     ‘counterQuery’ => ”
     )
);
```

2) In First Controller, add the Second Model usage as follows:

```
public $uses = array(‘First’,'Second’);
```

3) Finally print $this->paginate() and you will get the desired array.

> NTB: In the $hasMany array of First Model, add as many secondary tables as wanted.